# 3-D interpolation using griddata

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a problem for the interpolation of a 3-D array using griddata command in MATLAB. I have tried different ways but unfortunately I couldn't have handled it. The array which should be interpolated is a 182x125x35 array (longitude, latitude and depth) which is model output and I want to interpolate it on the observation data points. Thanks for the time you spend for helping me.

```
clear;
clc;

% Observation Data
t_obs = ncread('/disk1/Observation/data_from_data.nc','date_time');
lat_obs = ncread('/disk1/Observation/data_from_data.nc','latitude');
long_obs = ncread('/disk1/Observation/data_from_data.nc','longitude');
depth_obs = ncread('/disk1/Observation/data_from_data.nc','var1');
temp_obs = ncread('/disk1/Observation/data_from_data.nc','var2');


% Model Data
lat_m = ncread('/disk1/.../a.nc','GLat');
lon_m = ncread('/disk1/.../a.nc','GLong');
H = ncread('/disk1/.../a.nc', 'H');
sigma = ncread('/disk1/.../a.nc','SIGMAZZ');
dom = ncread('/disk1/.../a.nc','DOM');

% Rearrangement of date string to number for observation time
toffset1 = datenum([1990 01 01 00 00 00]) + datenum([0000 00 00 00 00   00]);
t = t_obs - 1;
time_obs = toffset1 + t;

% Selection of model file and date
t_mod1 = input('[yyyy mm dd] = '); 
t_mod2 = input('[yyyy mm dd] = ');
toffset = datenum([1990 01 01 00 00 00]) + datenum([0000 00 00 00 00 00]);
t_mod3 = t_mod1+(0.00000001);
t_mod4 = t_mod2+(0.00000001);
date1 = datenum(t_mod3);
date2 = datenum(t_mod4);

tind_m1 = date1;
tind_m2 = date2;

time_mod = [tind_m1:tind_m2]';


ind1 = zeros(16887,1);
ind2 = zeros(16887,1);

    for i = 1:16887 
        d = sort(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i))); 
        ind1(i) = find(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i)) == d(1)); 
        ind2(i) = find(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i)) == d(2)); 
    end
% Find temporal point of parameter for temporal interpolation

  for i = 1:16887
      d = sort(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i)));
      ind1(i) = find(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i)) == d(1));
      ind2(i) = find(abs(time_mod - time_obs(i)) == d(2));
  end

% Temporal and spatial interpolation and writing the output in a .nc file

c = 1;

for n = ind1(1):ind1(16887)
    for m = ind2(1):ind2(16887)
        for l = 1:16887
            str1 = sprintf('%4.4d',n);
            str2 = sprintf('%4.4d',m);
            sfile1 = (['/media/.../restart.',str1,'.nc']);
            sfile2 = (['/media/.../restart.',str2,'.nc']);

            temp1 = ncread(sfile1,'t',[1 1 1], [182, 125, 35]);
            temp2 = ncread(sfile2,'t',[1 1 1], [182, 125, 35]);

            temp_new = temp1 + ((temp2 - temp1)/(m-n))*(t(l) - n);

            temp_new = griddata(lon_m,lat_m,depth_m,temp_new,long_o,lat_o,depth_obs);


            c = n;
            str = sprintf('%4.4d', c);

            ncid = netcdf.create(['/disk1/.../tempinter/restartint.',str,'.nc'],'NC_WRITE');

            x = 1:182;
            y = 1:125;
            z = 1:35;

            dimid1 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'xdim',length(x)); 
            dimid2 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'ydim',length(y));
            dimid3 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'zdim',length(z));
            varidt = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'temp_new','double',[dimid1 dimid2 dimid3]);
            netcdf.endDef(ncid)
            netcdf.putVar(ncid,varidt,temp_new);
            netcdf.close(ncid);
            c = c+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: post the code you already have, as well as some input and desired output data

Comment: I added the code but unfortunately the input data is too large that I don' know how to put (attach) it here.

Comment: why not interp3? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html